# Portal Fantasy Games

Tags: game-recommendation, fantasy

I've been searching for a portal fantasy RPG without any luck. Does anyone know of such a system/setting?

For reference, portal fantasies are when a person from one world—typically ours—get transported to another world. Narnia's probably the most famous example. There's also The Magicians books and tv series and Sliders, to name a few.

I know I could make my own, but I'd rather use someone else's if the work's already been done.

Comment: Recommendation requests like this are off topic, for technical reasons. We have put together [a list of suitable discussion sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) where you can ask instead though!

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! To elaborate on SevenSidedDie's point, we generally work on a ~1:1 Q&A format, rather than discussion or suggestion posts. Recommendation questions like this have a lot of different possibilities, so that doesn't really fit the format of the site :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize. Is it appropriate to link the thread here? I've been getting some responses and recommendations over on reddit.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I think a comment linking to the reddit thread would be fine, for anyone who happens to come across this question in the future.

Comment: That sounds a lot to me like “sure, put an answer in a comment on a closed question.”

Comment: Okay…since I'm getting conflicting messages, I'll post the link and let someone who's more experienced make the call. https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/c6e4cc/portal_fantasy_rpgs/